# Cannot load file or assembly Microsoft.MSXML version 8.0

Tags: windows-10, msxml

What started the issue: My internet had dropped on the 5g band so I began trouble shooting to get the IP back. I saw that my non 5g band was valid and clicked connect on that WiFi connection to just get the internet back up quickly. Once I clicked connect, windows 10 locked up and blue screen shortly after. The OS started back up just fine but when I recovered my unsaved Visual Studios project, it seemed like things were corrupted at first glance, but it wasn't, everyone of my Visual studios projects load just fine, but when I click on a C++ or header file Visual Studios presents this error and I can't continue to code. I searched all over google to turn up an answer which none worked. Please help I have an assignment due tomorrow and I'm pressed for time.
Thanks for any responses in advance.

### So I found that the file is corrupt, how can I replace it?

What I have done to try and fix the issue.

- Repaired Visual Studios 2017
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studios 2017 Enterprise
- Installed MSXML Version 6.0, Verison 8 is not available for some reason?
- Command Prompt CHKDSK
- sfc /scannow after CHKDSK was ran and found corrupted files.

[image]
[image]

CBS log file from the scan now.
[Log File Download](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/272380123049754625/389547654688014337/CBS.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Download and install every Visual studios redistributable and 2015 update and tools.

I also repaired Visual studios 2010 as I had it installed even though I use 2017.

Then restart.

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/

[image]